# PHP Printing date variable in other language

Tags: php

I'am trying to change dates locale.For example ive got date variable, 2015/Jun/01, 2015/Jun/19/ 2015/Mar/14 and etc. this variable called $startDate. Im trying to change english to my locale lets say lt_LT. Here is the code which i tried to use:

```
$startDate = ($start_date ? $start_date->format($df) : '-');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'lt_LT.UTF-8');
echo strftime($startDate);
```

But it still prints dates in english, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) what is the result of setlocale()? 2) did you try setting the local before creating the date object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify output date format in strftime and also pass the $startDate as timestamp.

```
$startDate = "2015/Mar/14";
$startDate = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $startDate));
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'lt_LT.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%Y/%b/%d", $startDate);
```

Result

```
2015/Kov/14
```

More information about strftime on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Asume, that lt_LT.UTF-8 is missing on your system, as it's working very well on my system. When using unknown locales, it will print in english too.

When using Debian, try:
dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: It is known language.

Comment: so you have other php code which is giving you the correct language output? is it there lt_LT or really lt_LT.UTF-8? Which system are you using? Could you let us know an example content of $startDate after the first line of code?